# How to get object of object in JSON API response?

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic with Angular. I have a JSON API response and I want to get the items of an object inside an object, in this case, author items.

**JSON API response**

```
   {
    x{
     **authors**:{
      auth-sara-rts-2022: 
           Code: "rts"
           Contact:{
              email:"xx@gmail.com"
              phone:"0.."}
           [[Prototype]]: Object
      auth-sami-sgs-2022: 
           Code: "sgs"
           Contact:{
              email:"xx@gmail.com"
              phone:"0.."}
           [[Prototype]]: Object
           [[Prototype]]: Object
    }
    [[Prototype]]: Object},
    y{
    yy: "text"
    [[Prototype]]: Object}

 [[Prototype]]: Object}
}
```

Here is how to call the API in ts file

```
callAPI(body: any, header: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(API_URL+API_ENDPOINT,body,header);
}

 postAPI(body:any,header) {
    this.callAPI(body, header).subscribe(
      (data) => {      console.log(data.x.authors);

        } 
    );
  }
```

I get a list of authors, and I'd like to access the items in each author's collection (code and contact).

I tried this code, but it returned an undefined value.

```
console.log(data.x.authors[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is that you are trying to use Array notation (`data.x.authors[0]`) to access key/value pairs in an Object. In order to transform the `authors` Object into an Array, there are multiple approaches. I would propose `Object.entries`, which returns an Array of tuples, each tuple containing the key followed by the value:

```js
const authors = Object.entries(data.x.authors);
console.log(authors[0]); // ['auth-sara-rts-2022', { Code: 'rts', ... }]
```

Here are the MDN docs for `Object.entries()`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries